# Using docker-machine, how can I build a local Dockerfile on an ec2 instance without using swarm or compose?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

On my local machine, I've created an ec2 instance using docker-machine, using the following two commands:

```
$ docker-machine create \
       --driver amazonec2 \
       --amazonec2-open-port 8000 \
       --amazonec2-iam-instance-profile iam-user \
       default
```

`$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`

At this point, I'm stuck. I've navigated to a local directory where my `Dockerfile` is and tried running `docker build .` but that image gets built on my local machine. I've read the documentation, and there doesn't seem to exist anything like `docker-machine build`.

Am I not understanding docker-machine conceptually? Should I copy over my project code to the ec2 instance and try it that way? If so, wouldn't something like that be against the point of using docker-machine in the first place?

Comment: Do you have specific evidence that it’s using your local machine?  Usually the `eval $(docker-machine env)` command sets `$DOCKER_HOST` so all `docker` commands point at the remote/virtual machine.

Comment: @DavidMaze, you're right. I ran `$ eval "$(docker-machine env -u)"` to detach from the remote machine and I can confirm that locally, I don't have any images. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll upvote and mark as accepted... or I can delete this question and avoid the barrage of downvotes that may come my way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per David Maze's comment, I was mistaken, and the `docker build` is actually run on the remote ec2 instance. Running `$ eval "$(docker-machine env -u)"` points all docker commands to a remote/virtual instance.